# subprocess.Popen - `cwd` is not honored

Tags: python, subprocess, python-2.6

For whatever reason,

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
handle = Popen('echo %CD%', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, stdin=PIPE, cwd=r'C:\test')
print 'STDOUT::',handle.stdout.readline().strip()
```

Gives me:

```
STDOUT:: C:\Documents and Settings\myusername\Desktop
```

Windows XP (for whatever reason)
Python 2.6.6

Does this perhaps have any similarities to how windows executes commands in row such as:

```
C:\> cd "C:\test\" && echo %CD%
C:\
```

Which, is wrong.

Comment: Tested with Win7 and Python 2.6 and 2.7, works as expected (STDOUT:: C:\test). So this seems to be related to WinXP.

Comment: @RobertCaspary Figures, well thank you Robert, conclude this in a response and the points are yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with Win7 and Python 2.6 and 2.7, works as expected (STDOUT:: C:\test).

So this seems to be related to WinXP.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to change the current working directory, you could use:

```
os.chdir('c:\\test')
```

Note the double backslash as the backslash is a special character in Python that needs to be escaped.

Also, to check your current working directory, you can use:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: Doesn't work, tried that. `subprocess` doesn't honor the main process working directory. When started it gets the default terminal startup location and goes from there.